Cannot remove element on specific Woocommerce worpress page
I have an header on a wordpress website where I am adding an ecommerce using Woocommerce, I am changing the header on the ecommerce related pages. It is and Element and I am adding conditions from the menu to not display it on that pages. I cannot find a way to do that on the Single product pages. Any ideas on how to do it?
I tried to check the condition "Single product page" in the esclusion menu, and I also tried to only select a test product but it does not work. Is it a problem of plugin compatibility?

You can use is_product() to check whether you are on a single product page. Here are some other helpful functions: https://developer.woocommerce.com/docs/conditional-tags-in-woocommerce/
